# Preventing ActiveRecord save() on an instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, clone

I have an ActiveRecord model object `Foo`; it represents a standard database row.

I want to be able to display modified versions of instances of this object. I'd like to reuse the class itself, as it already has all the hooks & aspects I'll need. (For example: I already have a view that displays the appropriate attributes). Basically I want to clone the model instance, modify some of its properties, and feed it back to the caller (view, test, etc).

I do *not* want these attribute modifications getting back into the database. However, I do want to include the `id` attribute in the cloned version, as it makes dealing with the route-helpers much easier. Thus, I plan on calling `ActiveRecord::Base.clone()`, manually setting the ID of the cloned instance, and then making the appropriate attribute changes to the new instance. This has me worried though; one `save()` on the modified instance and my original data will get clobbered.

So, I'm looking to lock down the new instance so that it won't hurt anything else. I'm already planning on calling `freeze()` (on the understanding that this prevents further modification to the object, though the [documentation isn't terribly clear](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001873)). However, I don't see any obvious way to prevent a save().

What would be the best approach to achieving this?

Comment: If you need to mess around that significantly with the standard ActiveRecord object, there's probably a better way of approaching the problem.

Comment: I'm certainly open to alternatives

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use [ActiveRecord::Base#readonly!](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Core.html#method-i-readonly-21)

```
model = MyModel.find 1
model.readonly!
model.save!
```

it will raise ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord

Answer (score 4):

There might be a more idiomatic way to do this, but one way would be to set a virtual attribute and check it in a `before_save` callback. When you clone the object, set the virtual attribute – maybe something like `is_clone` to `true`. Then define a `before_save` callback for your model class that prevents the save if that attribute is set.

Answer (score 4):

`freeze()` seems to be achieving what I want, though in an ugly way.

```
x = Factory.create(:my_model)
x.save!    # true
x.freeze
x.save!
TypeError: can't modify frozen hash
```

I'm guessing that save() is trying to update the created/modified attributes, which fails because the attributes hash is frozen.

So, freezing will prevent the saving... but I'd appreciate a more reliable method with a more specific error message.

Comment: Just to clarify, freeze will prevent the instance being modified at all, while readonly! will allow modifications but prevent the modified instance being saved to the database.

Comment: Thanks for the update @DavidAldridge; I've changed my accepted answer.